# pythonでGriewankを3dグラフで出力する際にエラー

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

https://www.cs.unm.edu/~neal.holts/dga/benchmarkFunction/griewank.html
上記のサイトを参考にGriewankの3Dグラフをpythonで出力しようとしたのですがエラーが出ます
全く原因が分からないので詳しい方がいましたら教えてください
お願いします

ソースコード

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import math

def func1(self, chromosome):
    """F6 Griewank's function
    multimodal, symmetric, inseparable"""
    part1 = 0
    for i in range(len(chromosome)):
        part1 += chromosome[i]**2
        part2 = 1.0

    for i in range(len(chromosome)):
        part2 *= math.cos(float(chromosome[i]) / math.sqrt(i+1.0))

    return 1 + (float(part1)/4000.0) - float(part2)

x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = func1(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

エラー

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) ＜ipython-input-46-c8c05ada4569＞ in ＜module＞()
     22 
     23 X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
---> 24 Z = func1(X, Y)
     25 
     26 fig = plt.figure()

＜ipython-input-46-c8c05ada4569＞ in func1(self, chromosome)
     14 
     15     for i in range(len(chromosome)):
---> 16         part2 *= math.cos(float(chromosome[i]) / math.sqrt(i+1.0))
     17 
     18     return 1 + (float(part1)/4000.0) - float(part2)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

func1がベクトル演算に対応していません。ベクトル演算に対応させるためには、`math.cos`ではなくnumpyの`np.cos`を使うようにします。

2次元用のコードのサンプルは以下のようになります。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def func1(X, Y):
    """F6 Griewank's function
    multimodal, symmetric, inseparable"""
    c = np.sqrt(2.0)
    return 1 + (X*X + Y*Y)/4000.0 - np.cos(X/c) * np.cos(Y/c)

x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = func1(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

もし、元に関数`func1`を変更せずに使いたい場合は、次のように各要素毎に`func1`を計算する必要があります。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import math

def func1(chromosome):
    """F6 Griewank's function
    multimodal, symmetric, inseparable"""
    part1 = 0
        for i in range(len(chromosome)):
            part1 += chromosome[i]**2
            part2 = 1.0

        for i in range(len(chromosome)):
            part2 *= math.cos(float(chromosome[i]) / math.sqrt(i+1.0))

        return 1 + (float(part1)/4000.0) - float(part2)

x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.empty(X.shape)
for i in range(len(X)):
  for j in range(len(Y)):
      Z[i,j] = func1([X[i,j], Y[i,j]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: わかりやすく解説していただいて有難うございます，無事実行できました！